# Adding grade inside of $_SESSION array

Tags: php

I am learning PHP for school rn and I am kinda stuck on this. I am making a $_SESSION['grades'] which is a array that holds all grades. But everytime I fill in a new grade thru the form. It puts it in but it is always just stays the first one of the array. Array always stays like `Array ( [0] => 2 )` for me it looks like the array is getting reset everytime I run out somehoww. Thanks already guys!

```
    if (isset($_POST['schoolcijfer'])) {
        echo "<br /> <br />";
        
        session_start();
        $gradelist = array();
        $grade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "grade", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        
        $_SESSION['grades'] = $gradelist;

        if ($grade > 10 || $grade < 1) {
            echo "Cijfer moet tussen de 10.0 en 1.0 zijn!";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['grades'][] += $grade;
            print_r($_SESSION['grades']);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're clearing the array every time with `$_SESSION['grades'] = $gradelist;`. You only need to set it to an empty array once, if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks, that already helped alot. Only problem right now is that it this happens `Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => Array ( ) [2] => 7 [3] => Array ( ) [4] => 4 )` So as you might see when I submit a grade it puts it in the array but also adds another array element inside of the array.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `$_SESSION['grades'] = $gradelist;` part completely. If the `$_SESSION['grades']` array doesn't exist yet, trying to add an item to it with `$_SESSION['grades'][] += $grade;` will create an array automatically before adding the item. (By the way `+=` doesn't really make sense there, though it does work. You should use `=` instead.)